# How to classify image into Noisy image and Noise free image?

Tags: python, image, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have the dataset containing both noisy and noise free images. Noisy images are generated using different ISO and luminance condition. I tried with VGG16 pretrained CNN model (Using Python and Keras library) to classify them, but its failing to classify new set of images. So I want to know how to approach this problem? Can we solve this problem by using CNN models like VGG16, InceptionV3 etc? Is there any other method available to solve?

**CODE FOR VGG16 CNN model** :

```
#XX: total dataset containing 1000 images (500: Noisy, 500:Noise Free) 
# Original Dimension of image:(4000, 3000, 3)
#YY: Contains class for each image in dataset
import numpy as np
XX=np.array(XX).reshape(-1,224,224,3)
import pandas as pd
YY = pd.get_dummies(YY)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(XX,YY,test_size=0.3,stratify=YY)
```

```
#Model Creation
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense,Dropout
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.optimizers import SGD
num_classes=2
IMAGE_SIZE = [224,224]  

vgg = VGG16(input_shape = IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights = 'imagenet', include_top = False)
#For freezing the first 8 layers
for layer in vgg.layers[:8]:
       vgg.trainable = False

x = Flatten()(vgg.output)
x=Dropout(0.2)(x)
x = Dense(num_classes, activation = 'softmax')(x)  
model = Model(inputs = vgg.input, outputs = x)
opt = SGD(lr=0.000001)
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
#ImageDataGenerator
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
BATCH_SIZE = 32
def create_datagen():
    return ImageDataGenerator(
        zoom_range=0.15,  
        fill_mode='constant',
        cval=0.,  
        horizontal_flip=True,  
        vertical_flip=True, 
        rotation_range=360
    )

data_generator = create_datagen().flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

```
#Fit model
history = model.fit_generator(
    data_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=x_train.shape[0] / BATCH_SIZE,
    epochs=300,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test) 
)
```

**Got below result:**
Added results after 122 Epoch

```
Epoch 123/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3379 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.1180 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 124/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3511 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.1144 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 125/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2772 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.1156 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 126/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.4165 - accuracy: 0.9173 - val_loss: 0.1126 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 127/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3607 - accuracy: 0.9244 - val_loss: 0.1108 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 128/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.4563 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.1123 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 129/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.4268 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.1071 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 130/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3658 - accuracy: 0.9344 - val_loss: 0.1059 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 131/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.4448 - accuracy: 0.9187 - val_loss: 0.1078 - val_accuracy: 0.9734
Epoch 132/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.5164 - accuracy: 0.9201 - val_loss: 0.1059 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 133/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.4034 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.1040 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 134/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.4147 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.1019 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 135/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.4059 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 0.0975 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 136/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3722 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.0961 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 137/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3892 - accuracy: 0.9173 - val_loss: 0.0976 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 138/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3381 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.0978 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 139/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2899 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0967 - val_accuracy: 0.9767
Epoch 140/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.4291 - accuracy: 0.9230 - val_loss: 0.0927 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 141/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2823 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 0.0896 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 142/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1845 - accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.0878 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 143/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3070 - accuracy: 0.9244 - val_loss: 0.0880 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 144/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.4041 - accuracy: 0.9258 - val_loss: 0.0836 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 145/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2355 - accuracy: 0.9330 - val_loss: 0.0812 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 146/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3423 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.0811 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 147/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2270 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.0821 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 148/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.3257 - accuracy: 0.9287 - val_loss: 0.0807 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 149/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3776 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0820 - val_accuracy: 0.9801
Epoch 150/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2924 - accuracy: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.0796 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 151/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3149 - accuracy: 0.9387 - val_loss: 0.0789 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 152/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2694 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.0803 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 153/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3450 - accuracy: 0.9344 - val_loss: 0.0789 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 154/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2978 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0767 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 155/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3924 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.0759 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 156/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2532 - accuracy: 0.9358 - val_loss: 0.0766 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 157/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3752 - accuracy: 0.9315 - val_loss: 0.0722 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 158/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3317 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0740 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 159/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3688 - accuracy: 0.9344 - val_loss: 0.0737 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 160/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3354 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0732 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 161/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2827 - accuracy: 0.9372 - val_loss: 0.0731 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 162/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2141 - accuracy: 0.9458 - val_loss: 0.0721 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 163/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.3395 - accuracy: 0.9287 - val_loss: 0.0694 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 164/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2528 - accuracy: 0.9472 - val_loss: 0.0692 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 165/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2318 - accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.0691 - val_accuracy: 0.9834
Epoch 166/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2182 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0676 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 167/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.3260 - accuracy: 0.9387 - val_loss: 0.0665 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 168/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3035 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.0671 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 169/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2598 - accuracy: 0.9458 - val_loss: 0.0657 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 170/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2582 - accuracy: 0.9529 - val_loss: 0.0658 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 171/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3038 - accuracy: 0.9529 - val_loss: 0.0689 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 172/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2628 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0679 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 173/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2119 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 0.0687 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 174/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3272 - accuracy: 0.9358 - val_loss: 0.0702 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 175/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2615 - accuracy: 0.9358 - val_loss: 0.0700 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 176/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.3187 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0695 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 177/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2071 - accuracy: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.0679 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 178/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3139 - accuracy: 0.9401 - val_loss: 0.0661 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 179/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2771 - accuracy: 0.9429 - val_loss: 0.0643 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 180/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2328 - accuracy: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.0640 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 181/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.1790 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0624 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 182/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3432 - accuracy: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.0614 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 183/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2550 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0638 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 184/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2734 - accuracy: 0.9429 - val_loss: 0.0641 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 185/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2693 - accuracy: 0.9458 - val_loss: 0.0620 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 186/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2916 - accuracy: 0.9387 - val_loss: 0.0626 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 187/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2710 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0614 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 188/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2273 - accuracy: 0.9544 - val_loss: 0.0592 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 189/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2588 - accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.0579 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 190/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2744 - accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.0560 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 191/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.1692 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0566 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 192/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1953 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0561 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 193/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2281 - accuracy: 0.9544 - val_loss: 0.0550 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 194/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.1234 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0541 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 195/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2385 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0540 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 196/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2519 - accuracy: 0.9444 - val_loss: 0.0548 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 197/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2070 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0533 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 198/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2044 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0530 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 199/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2041 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 0.0533 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 200/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.3268 - accuracy: 0.9315 - val_loss: 0.0522 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 201/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1605 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0514 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 202/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2490 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0505 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 203/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2290 - accuracy: 0.9544 - val_loss: 0.0510 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 204/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2597 - accuracy: 0.9429 - val_loss: 0.0503 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 205/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1400 - accuracy: 0.9643 - val_loss: 0.0505 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 206/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2330 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 0.0492 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 207/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2049 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0492 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 208/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.2605 - accuracy: 0.9458 - val_loss: 0.0464 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 209/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.1611 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0471 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 210/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2058 - accuracy: 0.9501 - val_loss: 0.0462 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 211/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.2022 - accuracy: 0.9515 - val_loss: 0.0455 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 212/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1029 - accuracy: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.0451 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 213/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1800 - accuracy: 0.9472 - val_loss: 0.0453 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 214/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1471 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0446 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 215/300
22/21 [==============================] - 401s 18s/step - loss: 0.2121 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.0453 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 216/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.1735 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0444 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 217/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.1517 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0447 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 218/300
22/21 [==============================] - 401s 18s/step - loss: 0.1743 - accuracy: 0.9529 - val_loss: 0.0443 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 219/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.2412 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0440 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 220/300
22/21 [==============================] - 399s 18s/step - loss: 0.1964 - accuracy: 0.9643 - val_loss: 0.0423 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 221/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1996 - accuracy: 0.9415 - val_loss: 0.0417 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 222/300
22/21 [==============================] - 395s 18s/step - loss: 0.1773 - accuracy: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.0414 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 223/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.2102 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0417 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 224/300
22/21 [==============================] - 383s 17s/step - loss: 0.2043 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0405 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 225/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.2149 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0397 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 226/300
22/21 [==============================] - 406s 18s/step - loss: 0.1961 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0414 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 227/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.1673 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.0415 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 228/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.1591 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0416 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 229/300
22/21 [==============================] - 379s 17s/step - loss: 0.1636 - accuracy: 0.9715 - val_loss: 0.0414 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 230/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1692 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0407 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 231/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1970 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0408 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 232/300
22/21 [==============================] - 389s 18s/step - loss: 0.2229 - accuracy: 0.9486 - val_loss: 0.0394 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 233/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.1558 - accuracy: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.0394 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 234/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.1449 - accuracy: 0.9615 - val_loss: 0.0392 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 235/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.2053 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 0.0389 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 236/300
22/21 [==============================] - 402s 18s/step - loss: 0.1271 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0389 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 237/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1817 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0397 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 238/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1496 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.0398 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 239/300
22/21 [==============================] - 409s 19s/step - loss: 0.1831 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0387 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 240/300
22/21 [==============================] - 414s 19s/step - loss: 0.1413 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0385 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 241/300
22/21 [==============================] - 423s 19s/step - loss: 0.1639 - accuracy: 0.9643 - val_loss: 0.0383 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 242/300
22/21 [==============================] - 409s 19s/step - loss: 0.1129 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0382 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 243/300
22/21 [==============================] - 426s 19s/step - loss: 0.1635 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0385 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 244/300
22/21 [==============================] - 410s 19s/step - loss: 0.1603 - accuracy: 0.9558 - val_loss: 0.0378 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 245/300
22/21 [==============================] - 414s 19s/step - loss: 0.1672 - accuracy: 0.9544 - val_loss: 0.0379 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 246/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 19s/step - loss: 0.1782 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0375 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 247/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1594 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0367 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 248/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 19s/step - loss: 0.1425 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0361 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 249/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1300 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0363 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 250/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 19s/step - loss: 0.1535 - accuracy: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.0363 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 251/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 19s/step - loss: 0.1406 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.0352 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 252/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1816 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0344 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 253/300
22/21 [==============================] - 403s 18s/step - loss: 0.0873 - accuracy: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.0339 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 254/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.1713 - accuracy: 0.9586 - val_loss: 0.0334 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 255/300
22/21 [==============================] - 380s 17s/step - loss: 0.1089 - accuracy: 0.9786 - val_loss: 0.0327 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 256/300
22/21 [==============================] - 388s 18s/step - loss: 0.1547 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.0327 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 257/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.0888 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0331 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 258/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.1542 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0328 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 259/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1545 - accuracy: 0.9643 - val_loss: 0.0321 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 260/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1093 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0322 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 261/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.2043 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 0.0323 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 262/300
22/21 [==============================] - 406s 18s/step - loss: 0.0805 - accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.0321 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 263/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1556 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.0321 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 264/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1495 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0316 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 265/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1125 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0318 - val_accuracy: 0.9867
Epoch 266/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1254 - accuracy: 0.9715 - val_loss: 0.0315 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 267/300
22/21 [==============================] - 405s 18s/step - loss: 0.1122 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0303 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 268/300
22/21 [==============================] - 404s 18s/step - loss: 0.1786 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.0281 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 269/300
22/21 [==============================] - 394s 18s/step - loss: 0.1488 - accuracy: 0.9629 - val_loss: 0.0284 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 270/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.1153 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0271 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 271/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.1501 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0263 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 272/300
22/21 [==============================] - 376s 17s/step - loss: 0.1116 - accuracy: 0.9772 - val_loss: 0.0260 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 273/300
22/21 [==============================] - 377s 17s/step - loss: 0.1853 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0261 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 274/300
22/21 [==============================] - 403s 18s/step - loss: 0.1141 - accuracy: 0.9772 - val_loss: 0.0266 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 275/300
22/21 [==============================] - 386s 18s/step - loss: 0.0824 - accuracy: 0.9772 - val_loss: 0.0267 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 276/300
22/21 [==============================] - 378s 17s/step - loss: 0.1131 - accuracy: 0.9757 - val_loss: 0.0265 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 277/300
22/21 [==============================] - 399s 18s/step - loss: 0.0716 - accuracy: 0.9772 - val_loss: 0.0265 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 278/300
22/21 [==============================] - 406s 18s/step - loss: 0.0860 - accuracy: 0.9772 - val_loss: 0.0261 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 279/300
22/21 [==============================] - 409s 19s/step - loss: 0.1323 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0263 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 280/300
22/21 [==============================] - 415s 19s/step - loss: 0.1375 - accuracy: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.0262 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 281/300
22/21 [==============================] - 410s 19s/step - loss: 0.0969 - accuracy: 0.9757 - val_loss: 0.0258 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 282/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1487 - accuracy: 0.9715 - val_loss: 0.0257 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 283/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 18s/step - loss: 0.1220 - accuracy: 0.9729 - val_loss: 0.0256 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 284/300
22/21 [==============================] - 396s 18s/step - loss: 0.1316 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0256 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 285/300
22/21 [==============================] - 423s 19s/step - loss: 0.1575 - accuracy: 0.9601 - val_loss: 0.0265 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 286/300
22/21 [==============================] - 420s 19s/step - loss: 0.1653 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0261 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 287/300
22/21 [==============================] - 409s 19s/step - loss: 0.1240 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.0253 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 288/300
22/21 [==============================] - 410s 19s/step - loss: 0.1148 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0251 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 289/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1235 - accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.0255 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 290/300
22/21 [==============================] - 407s 18s/step - loss: 0.1931 - accuracy: 0.9643 - val_loss: 0.0243 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 291/300
22/21 [==============================] - 408s 19s/step - loss: 0.1951 - accuracy: 0.9700 - val_loss: 0.0244 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 292/300
22/21 [==============================] - 386s 18s/step - loss: 0.0943 - accuracy: 0.9786 - val_loss: 0.0240 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 293/300
22/21 [==============================] - 383s 17s/step - loss: 0.2295 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0238 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 294/300
22/21 [==============================] - 380s 17s/step - loss: 0.1028 - accuracy: 0.9743 - val_loss: 0.0238 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 295/300
22/21 [==============================] - 387s 18s/step - loss: 0.1162 - accuracy: 0.9672 - val_loss: 0.0236 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 296/300
22/21 [==============================] - 381s 17s/step - loss: 0.0669 - accuracy: 0.9800 - val_loss: 0.0233 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 297/300
22/21 [==============================] - 379s 17s/step - loss: 0.1472 - accuracy: 0.9658 - val_loss: 0.0230 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 298/300
22/21 [==============================] - 379s 17s/step - loss: 0.1105 - accuracy: 0.9757 - val_loss: 0.0222 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 299/300
22/21 [==============================] - 380s 17s/step - loss: 0.1339 - accuracy: 0.9686 - val_loss: 0.0212 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
Epoch 300/300
22/21 [==============================] - 379s 17s/step - loss: 0.0940 - accuracy: 0.9786 - val_loss: 0.0197 - val_accuracy: 0.9900
```

Comment: Hi Root, welcome to SO. Can you please be more descriptive regarding the CNN model you are using. If new sets are not being classified, maybe overfitting is happening? How big is your dataset? 
Please show what you've already have.

Comment: Hi regina_fallangi , I added code and results. Please Check. Thanks.

Comment: That's great! It's been a long time since I work with CNNs, but at first glance it looks like 1000 images for a dataset is very small. When I did my thesis the minimal amount to get something qualitative was usually 5000 thousand.

Comment: Try to multiply your dataset by flipping images (vertically and horizontally), slightly changing colors, maybe even less epochs so it does not overfit on such as small dataset?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.... I want to know is my approach to use CNN for classifying Noisy and Noise Free images is correct? if yes then I can plan to arrange more images.

Comment: According to my experience CNNs are very well suited for binary classification of images, so yes, I believe the approach to use a CNN is correct.
I for one used CNNs to look at pictures of the sky and decide if there was gonna rain or not and the success rate was outstanding good. I just copied the models that autonomous driving contests winners used. No need to reinvent the wheel with the model right away :)